# Gifted Chat Module for Electron (React Native)

Tags: react-native, electron, chat, react-native-gifted-chat

I'm building a chat app like Slack using electron but **react-native-gifted-chat** is not supported by electron.

My error is:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-gifted-chat/lib/GiftedChat.js

Is there any solution to use a gifted chat package in electron-based desktop apps?

Or any other package to make chat UI supported by electron?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `react-native-gifted-chat` in `electron` for obvious reasons. The package [react-native-electron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-electron) tries to provide extensions to [React Native for Web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) targeted to the Electron environment to support additional modules exposed by React Native.

As an alternative, I can recommend [RocketChat](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.Electron). It is published under the MIT license and is an open-source communications platform developed in JavaScript. It is written in the electron environment.

It really depends on what you want to do, but in my experience there isn't much you need to develop in order to use RocketChat. It is already working very reliable.

Comment: Yes, it is already a working app but I have to use any package like gifted chat in my own custom chat application.